# Unable to get $watch to listen to object property changes

Tags: angularjs

I have set of user names within an array as different objects and I'm trying to listen to change in the names in a directive. So when I type anything in the text the model changes so why doesn't the $watch fire on name change ?

JS

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.directive('mydirective', function() {
    return {
      link : function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
      scope.$watch(scope.obj.users , function(newValue) {
          console.log(scope.obj)
      },true)
    } 
    } 
});
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.obj = {

      "users" : [
         {
            'name' : 'user1'
         },
         {
            'name' : 'user2'
         } 
      ]

  }
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="user in obj.users">
      <input mydirective type="text" ng-model="user.name"/>
</div>
```

Plnk - http://plnkr.co/edit/PKp57zhoa7kvUthqB5Zn?p=preview

Comment: it should be `scope.$watch('obj.users' , function(newValue) {`

Comment: This will work too: `scope.$watch(function(){return scope.obj.users; }, function(newValue){ ... });`. The first parameter is expected to be either a string of a function.